# mapstruct - target payload is subclass, no cast to real type?

Tags: java, mapstruct

While using mapstruct we've got the following (sample) scenario:

Our target class "Zoo" holds some reference of "Animal". An animal can be a "Lion" or an "Elephant". Now we want to set the lion's teethLength or the elephant's trunk lenght depending on some source class's ("ZooMaker") property.

```
class Zoo {
 Animal animal;
...
```

```
class Animal {
 long size;
...
```

```
class Lion extends Animal {
 long teethLength;
...
```

```
class Elephant extends Animal{
 long trunkLength;
...
```

```
class ZooMaker {
String animal;
long lenght;
```

What we wanna do is to create the Animal in Zoo dynamically using mapstruct. But, if we use a FactoryClass

```
public class PayloadFactory {

    public Animal createAnimal() {
      return new Lion();    
    }
}
```

for this Mapper class:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class AnimalMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "animal.teethLength", source = "length")
    public abstract Zoo toZoo(ZooMaker zooMaker);
...
```

we get an error like:
Error:(10, 9) java: Unknown property "teethLength" in type Animal for target name "animal.teethLength". Did you mean "animal.size"?

Even using Lion as Factory's return type or using an ObjectFactory like

```
@ObjectFactory
    public Lion createLion() {
        return new Lion();
    }
```

causes the same problem? Any ideas how to solve that type conversion issue?

Comment: This is a correct behavior, the `teethLength` is not defined in `Animal` but `Lion`.

Comment: So there's no possibility to create subclass type dynamically using mapstruct?

Comment: I am not aware it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct is an annotation processor. This means that it uses only information available at compile time and not runtime.

In your example `Zoo` has the property `animal` of type `Animal`, so MapStruct can only map to properties known about `Animal` during compilation time. You'll have to do something else to map the type specific properties.

You can use `@AfterMapping` where you can do `instanceOf` checks, etc.

Comment: So, there’s no possibility e.g. an annotation attribute to indicate the resulting type while creating an animal? Something like this here but for objects deeper in the hierarchy: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#determining-result-type

Comment: With the ObjectFactory yiu control that, but you can't do it for the mapping. You'll have to come up with something else